# Связь между приложением и веб-сайтом

Tags: android

Неоднократно встречались сайты, которые позволяют запустить свое приложение Android на смартфоне пользователя при открытие веб-страницы этого сайта, если это приложение установлено на его смартфоне. Автоматически, либо при нажатии ссылки "Открыть в приложении"

Как это происходит? Как веб-сайт узнает, что у пользователя установлено приложение? Как открывается приложение автоматически?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Это [Deep Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking).

Вы в манифесте прописываете фильтры (`intent-filter`) и обработчики нужные. Тогда при открытии ссылок в вебе человек будет перенаправлен на конкретные `Activity` вашего приложения.